# "ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero"

Tags: python

I have no idea what I'm getting this error so I'm asking for help online. Please excuse my primitive codes as I'm only a beginner.

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

```
        while True:
            randomNum = random.randint(0, 99)
            if (number % randomNum) == 0 and number != 0 and randomNum != 0:
                result = number / randomNum
                break
```

Comment: What's not clearfrom the error? `randomNum` can be any number between 0 and 99 and the you use it to take the modulus of another number

Answer (score 1):

The `random.randint(a, b)` function includes bot `a` and `b` in the range of numbers which can be returned. So, in the case where 0 is returned by the function, the expression `(number % randomNum)` will have to divide by 0, resulting in a `ZeroDivisionError`.

In order to eliminate the chance of this scenario playing out, I recommend changing the lower bound of the `random.randint()` function from 0 to 1.

```py
while True:
    randomNum = random.randint(1, 99)
    if (number % randomNum) == 0 and number != 0 and randomNum != 0:
        result = number / randomNum
        break
```

However, you could also rearrange the expressions in your condition, which would produce the same result. Since the condition uses the `and` operator, if one of the inner expressions evaluates to `False`, the remaining inner expressions are ignored.

```py
while True:
    randomNum = random.randint(0, 99)
    if number != 0 and randomNum != 0 and (number % randomNum) == 0:
        result = number / randomNum
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want 0 in any case, I would suggest you to change the random to begin in 1 and do the `number` validation before the modulo, since that could cause the error. like this:

```
while True:
    randomNum = random.randint(1, 99)
    if number != 0 and (number % randomNum) == 0:
       result = number / randomNum
        break
```

Also, in case you don't want to change the random, you could do the first check for zeroes:

```
while True:
    randomNum = random.randint(0, 99)
    if number != 0 and randomNum != 0 and (number % randomNum) == 0:
        result = number / randomNum
        break
```

Comment: You can put all the condition in one `if`, just reorder them, like the other answers shows. Because as all are joined with `and` it'll stop at the first False, so if a number is 0 it won't go further

Comment: True, although, for a beginner would be better to see it in 2 steps rather, to understand where it fails if any

Comment: @JuanMedina Why would that be the case? It is not hard to deduce that if the inner expression of a Boolean expression evaluates to `False`, the entire expression will be `False`. It also would be better practice, since unnecessarily nesting `if` statements is generally bad practice.

Comment: Point taken. Changed my code and removed the unnecessary `if`

Answer (score 0):

In python ( and many other languages) in an if case, if you have and, the booleans are resolved left to right order. If one is false, and there is no or condition, the if function just passes to else (or nothing if there is no else)

In your case, you test : `number % randomNum first` , and in case `randomNum == 0` (wich you only test AFTER) it will throw `ZeroDivisionError`

Doing this will solve the issue :

```
import random
number = 5
while True:
    randomNum = random.randint(0, 99)
    if number != 0 and randomNum != 0 and (number % randomNum) == 0  :
        result = number / randomNum
        break
```